# FlexSlider: Way to change from displaying images to displaying text?

Tags: html, css, animation, flexslider

Regarding flexslider
Is there any way to modify it from displaying images to displaying only text?  Or is flexslider only for animating images?  If so, can you give me a hint what would have to be changed?
Thank You

For each slide in the slideshow I would like to display varying amounts of text only.  And I would like to reliably keep the slider controls responsive and in a standard position on the screen as each slide changes.  I am not really concerned with displaying the images.

In some of the li examples which can be found in the zippy-share link below, I associate an image file with the "flex-caption" CSS Selector found in flexslider.css file.  Using an associated image file for each text paragraph seemed like my best bet to force the slider controls to stay in that standard position as each slide changed.  Am I on the right track?

I am not really concerned with displaying image files.

An html version of this problem can be found at the zippy-share link below:
http://www51.zippyshare.com/v/46072947/file.html
[take a look at the li examples in the main index.html](http://www51.zippyshare.com/v/46072947/file.html)

Comment: Is it about animation of slides? If so `flexslider` animate the `li`, which means whatever that is in the `li`. Even if its an image or text that will be animated.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: just to let everyone know the answer of @SreekeshOkky is correct, just add what you need inside `li`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the image with the text you want to put. Please remember to modify the minItem and maxItem to fit your need.